# What structure should I use? Delphi 10.3

Tags: delphi

Want to process and return from function array of tuples, such this:

`[ [1, "hello", 11], [2, "world", 66] ]` or `[ ["hello", 1, 4, 10, "world"], ["its", 1, 2, 5, "me"] ]` or other cases

The length of inner lists can vary and equals to the number passed to the function.

Is there any collection or a combination of collections to process this?

Comment: You don't know the length of the inner lists, you say. Also, it seems like the types of the inner lists' elements vary. What are the restrictions on the inner types?

Comment: Looks like an array of record

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: But the OP wrote (s)he doesn't know the length of the "inner lists".

Comment: Fair. So it is a jagged array of some variant type

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand, it can be int, string, bool may be. Not the objects. Inner lists have the same length

Comment: "I don't know the length of inner or outer lists". "Inner lists have the same length." Seems to me that you need to spend quite a bit more time determining the specification of the problem. Don't ask us to solve a problem before you know what the problem is.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, as example I pass to function list, which length is 3. So inner lists would have this length - 3.

Comment: Don't ask the question in comments. Ask it in the question. Use the edit button above. Please make more effort to ask a clear and precise question. Time spent preparing a good question is vital.

Comment: Looks like Python lists. Mixed types, double quotes around strings... What is real problem to solve?

Answer (score 1):

If each element of the outer "list" is always a data structure containing one integer, one string, and one more integer, you should create a record type for this structure:

```
type
  TCarData = record
    Size: Integer;
    Model: string;
    Year: Integer;
  end;
```

Then you can use either a [dynamic array](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)#Dynamic_Arrays) of such records, `TArray<TCarData>`, or a [generic list](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Generics.Collections.TList), `TList<TCarData>`.

If you need to do things like appending a single car at a time to the "list", you should definitely use the generic `TList<TCarData>` approach (since you should avoid appending a single item at a time to a dynamic array). Otherwise, the dynamic array approach is tempting, since then the compiler will manage the "list's" lifetime for you -- you don't need to create and free the "lists" manually.

On the other hand, if the inner structure isn't fixed like this, you could let the inner objects be arrays of [`Variant`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Variant_Types_(Delphi)): `TArray<Variant>`. So the entire "list" will have type `TArray<TArray<Variant>>`.

Then each element in the outer "list" is an arbitrary-length array of values of any simple non-pointer type: integers, floats, strings, etc.